# Print different strings using same loop

Tags: python, string, printing

So I'm making this math problem generator. It picks 2 random numbers from 1-20, and a random math operator. I want it to print this:

num1 symbol num2 (e.g. 5 * 2)

But I can't figure out how to do that. This is what I get with my code:

num1 symbol num2 symbol (e.g. 5 * 2 *)

Here is my code:

```
import random

def problem():

    randsymbol = random.randint(1,4)

    if randsymbol == 1:
        symbol = "+"
    elif randsymbol == 2:
        symbol = "-"
    elif randsymbol == 3:
        symbol = "*"
    else:
        symbol = "/"

    for count in range (0, 2):
        num = random.randint(1,20)
        print(num,symbol)

problem()
```

I know the problem is because I'm printing both the numbers and symbol  inside the loop, but if I don't do that, then I can't print 2 different numbers. So if I take the code out of the loop, I'll  get something like this:
num1 symbol num1 (e.g. 5 * 5)

It only prints the symbol once, but prints the exact same number twice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    for count in range (0, 2):
        num = random.randint(1,20)
        print(num,symbol)
```

To this:

```
    num1 = random.randint(1,20)
    num2 = random.randint(1,20)
    print(num1,symbol,num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

def problem():
    randsymbol = random.choice(["+", "-", "*", "/"])
    num1 = random.randint(1,20)
    num2 = random.randint(1,20)
    print(f"{num1} {randsymbol} {num2}")

problem()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def problem():
    randsymbol = random.choice('+-*/')
    nums = random.sample(list(range(1,21)), 2)
    print('{} {} {}'.format(nums[0], randsymbol, nums[1]))
```

Examples

```
>>> problem()
14 * 6
>>> problem()
4 / 10
>>> problem()
7 / 10
```

You can then use a dictionary of those symbols to the functions in `operator` to evaluate this expression and return the value (for checking against the user input, for example)

```
import operator
import random

def problem():
    randsymbol = random.choice('+-*/')
    nums = random.sample(list(range(1,21)), 2)
    print('{} {} {}'.format(nums[0], randsymbol, nums[1]))

    ops = {'+' : operator.add,
           '-' : operator.sub,
           '*' : operator.mul,
           '/' : operator.truediv}

    return ops[randsymbol](nums[0], nums[1])
```

Examples

```
>>> problem()
15 + 16
31
>>> problem()
15 - 8
7
>>> problem()
8 - 16
-8
```